# RethinkDB index query with several .contains()

Tags: rethinkdb, compound-index, reql

I have the following query that works fine but is slow, however I can't figure out how to index it properly:

```
r.db('my_db')
.table('messages')
.filter({ community_id : community.id})
.filter(function(row){
    return row('mentions').contains(user.id);
})
.filter(function(row){
    return row('channels').contains(channel.id);
})
.orderBy(r.desc('created_at'))
.skip(0)
.limit(50);
```

I tried with the following index (using Thinky.js):

```
Model.ensureIndex("user_mentions", function(message){
    return message("mentions").map(function(user_id){
        return message("channels").map(function(channel_id){
            return [ 
                message("community_id"), 
                message("mentions").contains(user_id),
                message("channels").contains(channel_id), 
                message('created_at') 
            ];
        }); 
    });

}, {multi: true});
```

And then to query it I've tried this:

```
r.db('my_db')
.table('messages')
.between(
    [community.id, user.id, channel.id, r.minval], 
    [community.id, data.user.id, channel.id, r.maxval], 
    { index : 'user_mentions' }
)
.orderBy({index:r.desc("user_mentions")})
.skip(0)
.limit(50);
```

The messages table looks like:

```
id | community_id | mentions (array of user_ids) | channels (array of channel_ids) | created_at
```

But I end up getting zero results.
I greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this index will make the `between` query you wrote above work:

```
.indexCreate(function(message) {
  return message('channels').concatMap(function(channel) {
    return message('mentions').map(function(mention) {
      return [
        message('community_id'),
        mention,
        channel,
        message('created_at')
      ];
    });
  });
}, {multi: true});
```